# Asynchronous request in RESTFul WebService

Tags: web-services, rest, asynchronous

I need to create a REST based web service where the request will be handled asynchronously.
By asynchronous, I mean that the client will make the request and continue with its execution with out waiting for the response from the  service.Is it possible to achieve this?
I need to deploy the service in WebSphere Application Server.

Comment: Here is a good approach: http://restcookbook.com/Resources/asynchroneous-operations/

Answer (score 5):

So I am not sure if your question is about how to do asynchronous processing on the server, or how to handle asynchronous operations in a RESTful manner.  If it is the latter, then here is a summary of the approach suggested at: http://restcookbook.com/Resources/asynchroneous-operations/

Code your service method to

- (a) handle the requested operation asynchronously (using a separate
  thread most likely).
- (b) Immediately return a response code of 202-Accepted
- (c) In the response body, return a URI that represents the status of the requested operation.

Then code your client to:

- (a) Call the main service method.  When the response is completed, if the response code is 202, note the URI returned in the body.
- (b) In a background thread, periodically poll that URI, until it returns an indication that the operation is complete.

Comment: This one is more precise description      https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2011/06/02/asynchronous-operations-in-rest/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could create a Thread which calls your REST service. Maybe you could see how to achieve this here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: I will be hitting the web service from my web application(the client is basically a servlet). As far as I know creating a thread explicitly in a web application is not a good practice.

Comment: In general threads are a limited resource and care should be taken when creating them.  That does not mean that it is a bad practice to use threads.  How you do so depends on your application needs.  Is this application expected to serve a very large number of concurrent users?  If so, then you might want to look into thread pools.

Comment: Queing is another approach to consider.  Dedicate one or more background threads to the processing of these requests.  Have your web service simply put the requests in a globally-accessible queue.  The background thread(s) will then process the requests one at a time.  This approach has the advantage that you have full control over how many threads exist at any given time.