# Implement Async process for external service with callback to main Request - Spring

Tags: java, web-services, rest, spring-boot

I have a design problem to solve where my application is developed using `Spring`.

There is a `REST API` which have to be designed in the following way.

**Process request and call an external web service and get the results.**

> Start processing  -> Call External Web Service in async way.  External
>   service will inform main request once completes if main request is
>   still alive.      -> Continue to process main request.    -> Check if
>   async process completes in next 100millisec   -> If results arrived,
>   return Status 201 with new URI to get complete results.   -> If
>   external service is not complete, return Client with Status 202 asking
>   client to call back after some time.

I am thinking on how to achieve this solution.

I know we might have many solutions. 
But can I have some good approach/suggestions in achieving this? Not very detailed.

Please let me know if you need any more details on this if it is not clear.

**More updates:**
Main thread calls this web service in a new thread. 
New thread once completes its processing, informs main thread if alive. 
Otherwise just updates data in db.

Comment: See if [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102055/asynchronous-request-in-restful-webservice) on SO helps

Comment: Saw that posts. Partially yes. But i have a second problem to solve there. After calling async service, main thread should wait for a particular time and then return. So caller has to wait for a certain time within which if results are there, then return 201 otherwise 202.                                                         Also, I saw that it can be done using Spring @Async. Is that a good approach to use and do we have a timeout problem to solve there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in the following way. 
Use CompletableFuture to execute the async task instead of @Async from Springs.

Do future.get with a timeout option to see if the results are available. 
If not, add a future.thenAccept clause to handle callback.