# Spring Async - CompletableFuture with handler after Timeout is done

Tags: web-services, asynchronous, spring-boot, completable-future

I have a scenario where I call an external web service from my REST API using Spring Async. 
It returns a CompletableFuture and it is clear that we can wait for a time till external async operation completes. 
Main thread returns with Status 202 when timeout occurs for me. 
I want to handle when the async process completes so that I need to update a field in db. 
Where do we get this handler or how do I achieve this?
Because main thread would have already returned.

Posted a question previously on the same. 
[Implement Async process for external service with callback to main Request - Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123179/implement-async-process-for-external-service-with-callback-to-main-request-spr)
But now I am making it more specific

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand your question completely, but may [thenAcceptAsync](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenAcceptAsync-java.util.function.Consumer-) be what you are looking for?

```
    cf.thenAcceptAsync(resultOfCompletableFuture -> {
        //update a field in db with resultOfCompletableFuture
    });
```